# Win API to compare 2 directories

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

Is there an existing Win API which can be used to compare two different directories, find the extra files in destination directory and print them? Or if there is any other way. I am trying to compare them based on file size and file name.

I tried to find out on internet, but could not find any relevant links.
Could you please help here?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: No, there's nothing built-in that can do that. Use `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` to read each folder into a `std::set` and then use `std::set_difference` to find the differences.

Comment: @JonathanPotter
I am trying to extract all files from dir1 and dir2 in two different lists and then finding the difference in dir2. But I am not able to find out how to delete these differential files from dir2. Any suggestions please.

`std::list<CString> s1= allFilesinDir(dir1);`
`std::list<CString> s2= allFilesinDir(dir2);`
`std::list<CString> s3{};`
`std::set_difference(s2.begin(), s2.end(),
  s1.begin(), s1.end(),
  std::back_inserter(s3));`

`for (const CString &s4 : s3)
 cout << S4;`

Comment: You want to delete the files from disk? Use `DeleteFile()`. If they're folders, use `RemoveDirectory()` but you have to recursive delete the folder contents first.

Comment: Note that `std::set_difference` requires sorted content. `FindFirstFile` / `FindNextFile` do not guarantee that files/folders are returned in sorted order (if it happens, then that's just coincidence)! That's why @JonathanPotter recommended to use `std::set`, which automatically sorts on insert. `std::list` is the worst of all data types for that.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.
@JonathanPotter I tried `DeleteFile()`, but could not delete the files.

`for (const CString &s4 : s3)
{ 
    SetFileAttributes(s4, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL);  
    DeleteFile(s4);
}`

Comment: Check the return code, if the function returns false use `GetLastError()` to see what error code it sets.

Comment: @Raushan, you should add the path(relative or absolute path) to the Cstring `s4`, Otherwise `DeleteFile` will not find the specified file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you don't need to recursively compare the folders contained.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
std::set<CString> allFilesinDir(CString dir)
{
    std::set<CString> s;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(dir, &ffd);
    // List all the files in the directory with some info about them.
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return s;
    }
    do
    {
        CString filename = ffd.cFileName;
        s.insert(filename);
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
    return s;
}
int main()
{
    CString dir1 = _T("path1\\*");
    CString dir2 = _T("path2\\*");
    std::set<CString> s1 = allFilesinDir(dir1);
    std::set<CString> s2 = allFilesinDir(dir2);
    std::set<CString> s3{};
    std::set_difference(s2.begin(), s2.end(), s1.begin(), s1.end(), std::inserter(s3,s3.end())); 
    for (const CString &s4 : s3)
    {
        int remove1 = dir2.Find(_T("*"));
        dir2 = dir2.Left(remove1);
        CString FilePath = dir2 + s4;
        if (GetFileAttributes(FilePath) == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            SHFILEOPSTRUCT DirRemove;
            DirRemove.fFlags = FOF_NOCONFIRMATION;
            DirRemove.hNameMappings = NULL;
            DirRemove.hwnd = NULL;
            DirRemove.lpszProgressTitle = NULL;
            DirRemove.pFrom = FilePath;
            DirRemove.pTo = NULL;
            DirRemove.wFunc = FO_DELETE;
            SHFileOperation(&DirRemove);
        }
        else
            DeleteFile(FilePath);
    }

}
```

If you only need to compare different normal files, not folders, ignore the final processing of folders in the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I am facing an issue with line `int remove1 = dir.Find("*");` and I am not able to resolve it.
I get this error - _2 IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "ATL::CStringT<BaseType, StringTraits>::Find [with BaseType=wchar_t, StringTraits=ATL::StrTraitATL<wchar_t, ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>]" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (const char [2])
            object type is: ATL::CString_

Comment: @Raushan modified the charset of the project from UNICODE to Mutiple-Byte

Comment: @Raushan Modified the code to better support different character sets.

Comment: I have tried to simplify it even further. Can you please tell me if this is also fine or not?
Please find my comment below:
`CString dir1 = "path1";
CString dir2 = "path2";
std::set<CString> s1 = allFilesinDir(dir1);
std::set<CString> s2 = allFilesinDir(dir2);
std::list<CString> s3{};
std::set_difference(s2.begin(), s2.end(), s1.begin(), s1.end(), std::back_inserter(s3));

for (const CString & s4 : s3)
{
 CString path = dir2+ "/" + s4;
 SetFileAttributes(path, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL);
 DeleteFile(path);
}`

Comment: Wildcard(`*`) is  needed for `FindFirstFile`.  Otherwise, it will only find `path1`, `path2` directories, not the files in folder.Then, splice file path and name by removing wildcards. If you use `std::set`, remember to replace all `std::list` with `std::set`, including those in `allFilesinDir`

Comment: `std::back_inserter(s3)` need to be replaced by `std::inserter(s3, s3.end())` because `std::set` has no `push_back()` method. Also, If path is a directory, you can't delete it through `SetFileAttributes` then `DeleteFile`.